# Extract linux (admin) users report for remote hosts

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ssh, sed

I am trying to find the best way to extract a report of Linux users and also which one of them are admin. The targets are Debian (8,9) and Ubuntu (18,20). The final report would be very long, so I want the hostname in the first line, to identify each VM. I also want a short&bried report, with only the username, not all the details..

My code here is bringing some irelevant info , when pushing it to multiple hosts (via pssh):

```
#!/bin/bash

_l="/etc/login.defs"
_p="/etc/passwd"

## get mini UID limit ##
l=$(grep "^UID_MIN" $_l)

## get max UID limit ##
l1=$(grep "^UID_MAX" $_l)

echo ""
echo `hostname`
echo ""
echo "----------[ User Accounts ]---------------"
awk -F':' -v "min=${l##UID_MIN}" -v "max=${l1##UID_MAX}" '{ if ( $3 >= min && $3 <= max  && $7 != "/sbin/nologin" ) print $0 }' "$_p"
#users with UID >= 1000 (MIN) and UID <= 60000 (MAX)
#these users are allowed to login into system if shell is bash/csh/tcsh/ksh as defined in the /etc/shells file

echo "----------[ from which, Admin Accounts ]---------------"
echo `grep '^sudo:.*$' /etc/group | cut -d: -f4`
#users in sudoers group

exit 0
```

It brings garbage
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide concise, testable, **textual** (no images and no links) sample input and expected output so we can help you. Never name a variable `l` (or `_l` or `l1`) by the way as `l` looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd want to know is if a user can run *any* command with sudo (and potentially which commands).  Something like this is the best way to gather the necessary data (or use as the report):

```bsh
for u in $(compgen -u); do echo "# $HOSTNAME - $u"; sudo -l -U $u; echo; done
```

To me, knowing the shell and/or the UID_MIN or MAX seems irrelevant. Relying on a grep from /etc/group is insufficient.  Accounts with a false or non-interactive shell can still be sudo'ed to, i.e. `sudo su - falseshellaccount -s /bin/bash`. A user with sufficient sudo access can simply edit /etc/passwd and/or /etc/group to bypass the id limits, sudo may be backed by sssd, ldap, etc. It's best to simply use sudo to see if the user can run a command, or not.

`sudo -l -U $u` could also be the basis of a slightly more complex (or terse) report, e.g.:

```bsh
for u in $(compgen -u); do echo -n "# $HOSTNAME - $u"; if sudo -l -U $u | grep -vq "not allowed"; then echo -n " [admin]"; fi; echo; done
```

or

```bsh
for u in $(compgen -u); do if [ $(id -r -u $u) -gt 3 ]; then echo -n "# $HOSTNAME - $u"; if sudo -l -U $u | grep -vq "not allowed"; then echo -n " [admin]"; fi; echo; fi; done
```

or

```bsh
for u in $(compgen -u); do uid="$(id -r -u $u)"; uid=${uid:-"0"}; echo -n "# $HOSTNAME -"; if sudo -l -U $u | grep -vq "not allowed"; then echo -n " [ADMIN]"; fi; echo -n " uid $uid, $u"; echo; done
```

... and any of the above commands can be run within single quotes so they can be passed to ssh (or ansible, etc), i.e.

```bsh
ssh remote-host 'for u in $(compgen -u); do uid="$(id -r -u $u)"; uid=${uid:-"0"}; echo -n "# $HOSTNAME -"; if sudo -l -U $u | grep -vq "not allowed"; then echo -n " [ADMIN]"; fi; echo -n " uid $uid, $u"; echo; done'
```

Comment: Thank you, very interesting approach.
However, "compgen" is not installed by default, which is a problem for enterprise environments.
Also, "UID_MAX/MIN" is useful to filter users, because users with UID >= 1000 (MIN) and UID <= 60000 (MAX) are not able to login against the Shell.

Comment: @RookieRoo, what do you mean by "compgen is not installed"?  It's a Bash built-in command, and I don't know of any distribution that installs a Bash with that command somehow disabled.

Comment: $ compgen
-sh: 11: compgen: not found

$ cat /etc/*release
ID=azure
AZURE_IMAGE_VERSION="8.0.201807160"
BUILD_INFO_URL="https://azure-build.debian.net/job/image-jessie/1025/"
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"